# Azure portal application settings: "Failed to load settings" (ReadOnlyDisabledSubscription)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

In the Azure portal I select my web app and then "Application settings" and it shows this:

[image: Failed to load settings]

An error message, "Failed to load settings", for application settings and also for connection strings.

How do I fix this?

Additional information:
Another user with the same privileges than me is also experiencing this issue when going to the same Application settings page. Also I'm able to deploy so I have the privilege to modify web.config

Additional information #2:
So I used Chrome Inspector as suggested and its trying to get application settings with a POST to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx/config/appSettings/list?api-version=2015-08-01

This is the JSON response:

```
{
   "error": {
       "code":"ReadOnlyDisabledSubscription",
       "message":"The subscription 'xxxxxxxxxx' is disabled and therefore marked as read only. You cannot perform any write actions on this subscription until it is re-enabled."
   }
}
```

Comment: Pragmatic solution: delete and re-create the app. You could also try Azure PowerShell?

Comment: Try to refresh the page (or) Restart the web app

Comment: press F12 and check the REST Requests and  JSON responses for some further insights

Comment: i've updated my question with the REST request and JSON response

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround to this issue?  Experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the Azure portal has bugs.
Also try https://preview.portal.azure.com, occasionally that works for me when the main portal has errors.