# I can't access to my application Settings in azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

[image]

I want to make some question in my application settings. However this message keeps showing even after I click the refresh button. I don't understand why is happening.

Comment: If you haven't already, take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318220/azure-portal-application-settings-failed-to-load-settings-readonlydisabledsu    It doesn't have an accepted answer, but some of the comments and question edits might help.

Comment: This is happening when azure updates scripts or making changes in api. Try to hit refresh button in browser or try again later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it happens. Can you try restarting the web app or refresh the portal and see. If both do not work try to create the web app again.